# Python filter() object list with variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter

I have a generic question, I've been using list comprehension with python for a while, but I came across filter(), where you could pass in a defined function, to filter a list of objects.

```
filteredList = filter(filterfunction, listOfItemsToFilter)
```

Is it also possible to pass in the attribute you want to test for?

```
class testObject(object):
    def __init__(self, att1="", att2="", att3=""):
        self.att1 = att1
        self.att2 = att2
        self.att3 = att3

def t_filter_function(item):
    if item.att2 == 'item 2':
        return True
    else:
        return False

def printer(list):
    for item in list:
        print(item.att1, item.att2, item.att2)

def main():
    testObjectList = []
    testObjectList.append(testObject(att1='1', att2='item 1', att3='a'))
    testObjectList.append(testObject(att1='2', att2='item 2', att3='b'))
    testObjectList.append(testObject(att1='3', att2='item 2', att3='c'))

    printList = filter(t_filter_function, testObjectList)

    printer(printList)

main()
```

What I'd like to do, is to extend the function t_filter_function() so that I can pass in a variable, such that I could test for any value of att2,

```
printList = filter(t_filter_function('item 2', testObjectList), testObjectList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `t_filter_function` in order to take an additional parameter which will be the attribute value you want to test:

```
def t_filter_function(item,attr):
    if item.att2 == attr:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then you can modify your `filter` function:

```
printList = filter(lambda elem: t_filter_function(elem,'item 2'), testObjectList)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options. You could create a new function that takes a list and a target and filters to the items that match that target:

```
 def filter_to_target(target,starting_list):
     return filter(lambda x: x == target, starting_list)
```

You could create a function that returns a function that checks equality to the target, and then use that in `filter`:

```
def get_filter_function(target):
    return lambda x: x == target

filter(get_filter_function(target),starting_list)
```